# How to find "Cheapest Hotel Rate"?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

> Hotel Management
>
> A well renowned hotel has three branches in miami. Namely x,y and
>   z(Actually they gave names).Each has two types of customers. Regular
>   and Rewardee. Also each branch has its own ratings x is given a 3 star
>   rating while y has 5 star rating and z has 4 star rating.
>
> Each hotel has specific rates for weekend and weekdays. x charges $100
>   for regular customers on weekdays and $120 on weekends While it is $90
>   for rewardee on weekdays and $60 on weekends. Similarly y charges $130
>   for regular customers on weekdays and $150 on weekends. While its $100
>   for rewardee on weekdays and $95 on weekends. While z charges $195 for
>   regular customers on weekdays and $150 on weekends. While its $120 for
>   rewardee on weekdays and $90 on weekends. Now when the customer
>   requests for a particular detail you need to find which hotel would
>   yield the customer profit. In case of tie between hotels compare the
>   ratings and provide the result.
>
> Input format:
>
> regular: 16Mar2010(sun), 19Mar2010(wed), 21Mar2010(Fri)

i have made this code... please tell me if i am moving in the right direction. also how can i make the hotel prices dynamic

```
getTheday = function(aText,typeofcustomer)
    {

        this.typeofcustomer = typeofcustomer;
        myDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
        if(new Date(aText).getDay() == 0 || new Date(aText).getDay() == 5 || new Date(aText).getDay() == 6)
        {
            console.log("its weekend!!!");
            this.weekend(this.typeofcustomer);
        }

        console.log("it is ", myDays[new Date(aText).getDay()]);

    }

    getTheday.prototype.weekend = function(typeofcustomer)
    {
        console.log(typeofcustomer);
        this.hoteloptionsforweekend();
    }

    getTheday.prototype.hoteloptionsforweekend = function()
    {

        if(this.typeofcustomer == "rewardee")
        {
            this.hotelpricex_ = 60;
            this.hotelpricey_ = 95;
            this.hotelpricez_ = 90;
            this.minhotelprice = Math.min(this.hotelpricex_, this.hotelpricey_, this.hotelpricez_)

            console.log("min price is of hotel", this.minhotelprice);

        }

        if(this.typeofcustomer == "regular")
        {
            this.hotelpricex_ = 120;
            this.hotelpricey_ = 150;
            this.hotelpricez_ = 150;

        }

    }
```

Comment: no.... its not.. i have made the enitre code... i want to optimize it

Comment: Well, to start with, `this.rewardee;` and `this.regular;` on lines 3 and 4 make no effect – you are free to remove them

Comment: I would start with building an object representing each hotel and the different rates: e.g. `rates = {x: {daily: 150, weekend: 200, special: 95}, y: { ... }}`. Then, come up with some code to search that data.

Comment: http://dc251.4shared.com/doc/mBkTDfej/preview.html 
a link to the question

Comment: but what if the rates have to be changed later..... is thr anyway to change it ? as in by making it public or something like that

Comment: @TanyaNair the format of Stackoverflow is Q&A, where the objective is to understand and address a specific problem, idea, or bit of code. Not look over the entire program. Perhaps if you narrowed the question down to something more specific then "moving in the right direction"

Comment: @ZakParks maybe i am framing the question wrong.. but i just want to know how can i make this code work.. as in optimize

Comment: @TanyaNair theres a difference between optimize and "make work". If it won't compile (aka doesnt work) then what errors are you getting? If you are looking for optimization, how are you looking to do so (speed, length of code, etc)?

Comment: @TanyaNair you may want to look at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/ . Your question was most likely downvoted because it fell under the category of "look at the code and find something wrong" rather than "how do I fix this error" or "how do I make this faster" or "how do I implement such-and-such an algorithm". Besides, it's not worth it to fret about _points on the internet_.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Put your price listings outside of the constructor
// so that you could fetch them from somewhere else
// later
var hotelPrices = [
        {
            name:    'Hotel X',
            daily:   { regular: 120, rewardee: 60 },
            weekend: { regular: 140, rewardee: 70 }
        },
        {
            name:    'Hotel Y',
            daily:   { regular: 150, rewardee: 95 },
            weekend: { regular: 180, rewardee: 110 }
        },
        {
            name:    'Hotel Z',
            daily:   { regular: 150, rewardee: 90 },
            weekend: { regular: 180, rewardee: 110 }
        }
    ];

// Be consistent and use correct camelCase for naming.
// And, btw, `getTheDay` name is misleading and confusing.
getTheDay = function( aText, typeOfCustomer, prices ) {
    var day = ( new Date( aText ) ).getDay();

    this.typeOfCustomer = typeOfCustomer;
    this.prices = prices;

    // isWeekend is a Boolean, indicating whether the date passed
    // is a weekend. 
    this.isWeekend = day == 0 || day == 5 || day == 6;
};

getTheDay.prototype.getMinimumPrice = function() {
    var prices = [],
        i, len;

    for( i = 0, len = this.prices.length; i < len; i += 1 ) {
        // Taking the appropriate price from the price list
        // and moving it to the new list
        prices.push( this.prices[i][ this.isWeekend ? 'weekend' : 'daily' ][ this.typeOfCustomer ] )
    }

    // A small trick to feed Math.min an array
    // instead of a list of arguments
    return Math.min.apply( Math, prices );
};

// Example usage:
var hotelRates = new getTheDay( aText, typeOfCustomer, hotelPrices );
console.log( hotelRates.getMinimumPrice() );
```

Now your home task is to create a method that will return the name of the cheapest hotel. There is a good series of articles for JavaScript beginners is being published now on DailyJS: [JS 101](http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#js101)

Comment: getTheDay = function( aText, typeOfCustomer, prices )

prices is for ?

Comment: `prices` will be referencing any object that you pass as the third argument to the `getTheDay` constructor. It's `hotelPrices` in the example at the very bottom of the listing